# Using replace in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I'm having trouble replacing values in a column. I have data coming into the column as a letter attached to a number.

output

```
J/2022
F/2022
```

I would like my output to be just the letters(Like J instead of J/2022)

My current code

```
df['Month'].replace(to_replace='J/2022', value='J')
```

But when I do this the output still comes out as J/2022. How to I replace J/2022 with J?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. `pd.Series(["J/2022", "F/2022"]).replace(to_replace="J/2022", value="J")` leaves `J` only, as expected

Comment: Are you saving the output of replace in any variable? The replace method returns a new DataFrame, instead if you use inplace=True it replaces and stores the result in the DataFrame itself.

Answer (score 0):

If your just trying to get the first letter of the string that is "J/2022" and there is always one letter simply do `df["month'].map(lambda x: x[0])` this would produce a series of all of the letters.